# Can't access ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I tried to save or load some data when my app is terminating. In my ViewController.m I made 2 functions, one for saving and one for loading.

In my AppDelegate.m I tried to access my ViewController, but it doesn't seem to work..

I tried a couple of different ways that I found here on stack overflow, but the Delegate doesn't recognize it as a ViewController or something:

```
[self.ViewController myFunction];
[self.rootViewController myFunction];
[self.window.ViewController myFunction];
```

They all don't work. What am I doing wrong? Am I using the wrong name for the ViewController?

I'm using storyboards by the way.. Is the accessing method different here?

Comment: Where and how did you declare your property leading to your viewController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to do initialization of object of your `self.viewController` such like

```
self.ViewController = [[ActualNameOfViewController alloc] init];
```

And then call method such like

```
[self.ViewController myFunction];
```

Might be this is helpful :)

Comment: I think you're right.. But where should I put the first statement? I only have a ViewController, is this the actual name also? Thanks for your answer. I will upvote it once I got it working :)

Comment: @RomanStrijbos in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` after `window` created.. and `ActualNameOfViewController` it is just name for understanding you :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that ViewController is imported than do alloc and init

```
////#import "ViewController.h"
ViewController *MyVc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
[MyVc myFunction];
```

Answer (score 0):

Import your `UIViewController` class in `AppDelegate.m` class :

```
#import SampleViewController.h
```

after that create an instance of `UIViewController`:

```
self.sampleViewController = [[SampleViewController alloc] 
                                   initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" 
                                            bundle:nil];
[self.sampleViewController myFunction];
```

SampleViewController is xib name for that `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thanks! Where do I put the alloc/init? After my implementation?

Comment: yeah, do one thing put alloc/init in - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification   after that you can use that instance anywhere to call funtion of view controller